# Maximum Pisano Periods

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, fibonacci-numbers

Let $\{F_i\}_{i\geq 0}$ denote the Fibonacci sequence, where $F_0=0$, $F_1=1$, and $F_{i+1}=F_i+F_{i-1}$ for $i\geq 1$. Let $p$ be an odd prime number. The Pisano period $\pi(p)$ is the least positive integer $k$ such that $F_{k} \equiv 0 \pmod p$ and $F_{k+1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$. If $p \equiv 1,4 \pmod 5$, then $\pi(p) \mid (p-1)$. This follows from Binet's formula and Fermat's little theorem. If $p \equiv 2, 3$, then $\pi(p) \mid 2(p+1)$.

The list of Pisano periods modulo primes is given by [A060305][1]: 3, 8, 20, 16, 10, 28, 36, 18, 48, 14, 30, 76, 40, 88, 32, 108, 58, 60, 136, 70, 148, 78, 168, 44, 196, 50, 208, 72, 108, 76, 256, 130, 276, 46, 148, 50, 316, 328, 336, 348, 178, 90, 190, 388, 396, 22, 42, 448, 456, 114, 52, 238, 240, 250, 516, 176, 268, 270, 556, ...

From this list, the maximum Pisano periods i.e., when $\pi(p)=2(p+1)$, occur for primes: 3, 7, 13, 17, 23, 37, 43, 53, 67, ...

In [this article][2], the following question is stated as an open problem:

**Question:** Are there infinitely many primes $p \equiv \pm 3 \pmod{10}$ such that $\pi(p)=2(p+1)$?

Do you know if there are any other references (preferably published) that state this question, or do you know any updates regarding this question? Thank you!

[1]: https://oeis.org/A060305#:~:text=Pisano%20periods%20for%20primes%3A%20period,numbers%20mod%20prime(n).&text=Assuming%20Wall's%20conjecture%20(which%20is,A007283(k%2D1).
[2]: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.04582.pdf

Comment: I d.k. But there is an unsolved conjecture that for every prime $p$, if $\mu(p)$ is the least $m>0$ such that $p|F_m$ then $p^2\not |F_{\mu(p)}$. I d.k. whether this affects your conjecture.

Comment: I suppose you have checked [OEIS A071774](https://oeis.org/A071774) where it is conjecture that primes $p \equiv \pm 3 \pmod{10}$ such that $\pi(p) \neq 2(p+1)$ are those in [OEIS A216067](https://oeis.org/A216067) (this is a recent note).